# Android update not proceeding beyond the point of earlier cancellation

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, updates

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note N7000. An Android update was promoted. I started with the update download, but canceled it at 36 MB (total update size:110 mb) because of slow network. After that, whenever I try downloading it, the download stops at the 36 Mb(exactly at 35.88 where I had previously canceled it).

Interestingly, it is the same case with app downloads also, from Google Play.

Device: Samsung galaxy note - GT-N7000.
Android version: 4.0.3

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when an app size is less than 35.88 Mb?

Comment: It happens only for the apps/Android update which I manually canceled when the download is in progress.

For example, I'm canceling app1 in the middle. I'll be able to download any other app and install. But when I try to download app1 again, download stops at the same point, where I had canceled during the earlier installation attempt.

Comment: Wow.. interesting problem.. Have you reported this to Google?

Comment: Not yet. Just wanted to see if any one else out there with the same problem(and of course, any solution).

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the temporary file that is 36Mb in size and re-start the download again this time.

Please include the method in how you're downloading the update - if you are using Kies, be sure to exit Kies first completely, then look for that temporary file (it will be in a hidden spot within the temporary directory under Windows - not sure of the path `C:\Documents And Settings\Users\XXXX\Local Data` ** OR ** `C:\Documents and Settings\Users\XXXX\Application Data` or similar)

You can easily find that out by searching for it depending on where the Windows Environment Variabel $TEMP points to.

Comment: I am trying to update via FOTA. I am not using Kies. I have searched for any temp file with a nearly equal size(when my download was cancelled) in my phone, but couldn't find one.

Comment: The issue is solved now. I was able to update using FOTA now. (I haven't changed anything materially in my phone.)